# How do I create new users in Stream-Chat using data from FirebaseAuth?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, getstream-chat

I'm trying to make a chat application which uses FireBaseAuth as authentication service and stream chat as chat service. I want to create a new user in stream chat as soon as the user is authenticated from firebase. How to I do that?

I've already tried Authenticate-with-streamChat firebase extension and it is giving me a very hard time using it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You're right, the [Authenticate with Stream Chat](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stream-auth-chat) Firebase extension is the best option for this. Did you try creating some test users via the Authentication tab of the Firebase Console?